# Interfacing with a micro display module

Tags: display, interface

I'm planning a project for which a tiny (maybe 1-2cm diagonal) display would be ideal. Some devices exist (mostly for camera viewfinders or projectors) but I have no idea about how to interface with it using (for example) raspberry pi or arduino. Does anyone know how to talk with these devices or to convert them to (e.g., HDMI).

https://www.sony-semicon.co.jp/e/products/microdisplay/lcd/technology.html
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001014550808.html

Comment: use a module instead ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=oled+module&ia=web

Comment: Those Sony displays are for projectors, so they have no backlight etc. Probably not suitable. The OLED displays in the same link seem more appropriate, and they are specified to have an LVDS interface which is pretty straight forward to get from HDMI. But without a datasheet you're in for a ride trying to figure out how to drive it properly.